# R Loading Library Changes GUI Console Behavior

Tags: r, console, mouse

In R 3.3.1 on Win10, loading certain libraries changes the behavior of the console (R gui shell). If I start a fresh R session, I can use the mouse to help edit my commands, by placing the cursor anywhere in the current command string. But after loading certain libraries, I can't. For example, if I enter a command string:

```
R> x <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

I can click to the right of the 2, and then use `backspace` to erase it. This is normal behavior for most programs (e.g. Word, Notepad). But if I load the `raster` library:

```
R> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp

Attaching package: ‘raster’
```

and then retrieve the previous command (i.e. using ↑), when I try to click on the 2, or anywhere in the string, nothing happens. The only way to move the cursor is to use the arrow keys (i.e. move cursor forward or backward, one character at a time). The problem does not arise with all R packages. For example, `MASS` does not cause it, but `rgdal` does. This is of course very annoying and really slows down my work.

Has anyone else experienced this? How can I prevent this?

Comment: The first step is updating R to 3.3.2 which is now being available for 3 months. You may need consider installing/updating R Studio as well.

Comment: @Masoud: thanks for the suggestion. After upgrading to 3.3.3 (the latest version) the problem remains.